# Type hints for dynamically added methods from another Object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I add type hints to attributes that are added dynamically when  overriding `__getattr__`.

Imagine the following classes. I would like to add type hints so IDE's auto-complete for the `topping_cost` method.

```py
class Topping:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def topping_cost(self) -> int:
        return 3

class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, topping: Topping) -> None:
        self.topping = topping

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if hasattr(self.topping, attr):
            return getattr(self.topping, attr)
        raise AttributeError(f'Missing attr {attr!r}')
```

When it's called like the below I would like it to be type hinted (so IDE's provide autocomplete).

```py
mushroom_topping: Topping = Topping('mushrooms')
pizza: Pizza = Pizza(mushroom_topping)
print(pizza.topping_cost())      <=== I need IDE's to recognize that topping_cost is available to Pizza. How can I type hint this?
```

Comment: I think you're getting hints that this is a poor design. Delegating to the topping doesn't make sense - a topping is not a pizza. The topping should have a cost, then the pizza could have a topping_cost method that sums the costs of all toppings.

Comment: You cannot really give static type hints for dynamically created attributes.

Comment: I agree with you, @jonrsharpe; this is not my "actual code". However, even if conceptually this is bad practice, I am asking if this can be achieved from a technical perspective.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, in this particular case I know that `Pizza` will **always** have access to **all** methods of the `Topping` class.

Comment: Without a more representative example it's hard to say what should happen. In this case a `Pizza` effectively _is a_ `Topping`, only you've done that via dynamic delegation instead of inheritance - just use the latter and the IDE can help you out again.

Comment: Yeah, so what? How does that change anything?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I appreciate your solutions but it won't help me in this case. In my personal code inheritance would make the situation worse. I'm really looking for a solution to this very particular case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it changes things because it's not entirely dynamic. If only there was same way to use type hints that "all `Pizzas` always contain all the methods of `Pizza` and **also** all the methods of `Topping`.

Comment: Then you'll have to tolerate a lack of autocompletion for those methods.

Comment: It looks like it :(

Comment: thanks jonrsharpe, juanpa.arrivillaga